# How to deploy JavaEE 7 / JPA 2.1 Dynamic Web Application to IBM Liberty Profile WITHOUT web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty, jpa-2.1, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a Dynamic Web Application that access a DB2 v10 zOS Database.

I wish to use Hibernate 5 as my JPA 2.1 Provider and access my EntityManager via CDI.

I do not want to use the Spring Framework at all; I also do not wish to have a web.xml file.

How can I configure my persistence context and persistence unit WITHOUT using web.xml when deploying my application to WebSphere Application Server Liberty v9 Beta?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What worked and what didn't work?  (What do you mean specifically by "dynamic web application"?)

Comment: @bkail "dynamic web application" is referring to the type of project you create in an eclipse environment

Comment: @bkail i have tried defining the datasource in the server.xml and using a persistetnce.xml, the "injected" EntityManager" is always null though.

Comment: You probably need to add an Resource annotation on a Servlet class. I've managed to get JPA and Servlet working this way, but you need a resource reference and Resource on a servlet will do that for you. You should specify the name on Resource in common with what is in persistence.xml.

Comment: Do you have jpa-2.1 and cdi-1.2 features enabled? What is the data source JNDI name that you use in the `persistence.xml`? Do you have `<provider>` element defined in it? But I'd suggest to stick with default EclipseLink provider.

Comment: i have all required features enabled. the jndi data asource is setup and i have <provider> defined. I do not like EclipseLink provider, I wish to use Hibernate 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result on google for "websphere liberty hibernate" gave me the link to a sample app that uses Liberty with Hibernate.

[WASdev Liberty + Hibernate sample](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/osi-Java_Persistence_API_JPA_Hibernate_Sample)

Note that the jpaApp.war DOES use a web.xml, but this can easily be avoided by using the proper `@WebServlet` annotation and changing the `persistence.xml` to point to a server-defined datasource instead of a component-defined datasource.

```
@WebServlet(displayName="JPA Servlet", urlPatterns="/JPAServlet")
public class JPAServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That sample app is JPA 2.0 and uses a web.xml. My question relates to Liberty, JPA 2.1, and WITHOUT web.xml. I believe i can still define my data source (with jndi name) in the liberty server.xml, i need to know how to define the persistence context and entity manager without using web.xml. I should have been clearer my dynamic web app is JAXRS I do not want any mention of (AT)WebServlet or extend HttpServlet.

Comment: @Hector, you should still be able to use a lot of the sample.  Just update server.xml to have the `jpa-2.1` feature, user newer hibernate libs.  I also believe you can use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to avoid needing to specify `<persistence-context-ref>` in the web.xml as well.